# Post data to slim framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, slim

Used this method to post data to slim framework, but I am not getting the response. Can anyone please guide me on how to do it.

1.If I send a string URL as http:/myurl/parameter, then i am able to post it to the server else I get an error.

2.If I send the parameter along with the string URL itself, what should json as string contain.

```
-(void)sendRequestToURL:(NSString*)stringURL withJSON:(NSString*)JSONAsAString{
        NSError *jsonERROR =nil;
        __block BOOL success = NO;
        NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];
        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
        request.HTTPBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSONAsAString options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonERROR];
        NSLog(@"jsonERROR %@", jsonERROR) ;
        if (!jsonERROR){
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError * error) {
                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResonse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                if (httpResonse.statusCode == 200 ) {
                    success = YES;
                    NSLog(@"success %@", response) ;
                }
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"jsonERROR: %@", jsonERROR.description);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1)Maybe status code isn't 200.2)Try to debug, put breakpoint on response variable, if this breakpoint isn't reached for some reason your request is unsuccessful. 3) If request is ok, check error variable of completion block.

Comment: You're not handling results correctly from your call to `-sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`. You always check the result first: is it nil or non-nil? Only if it's nil do you then make use of the NSError that is returned by reference.